# difference between hasmany belongsTo , namedQuery belongsTo and hasmany instantiation grails domain

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

In grails, I have two domain classes Question and QuestionOption.One question have many options.Each option has a question.
I went through 4 different scenario.
These scenarios has combination of instantiation-namedQuery , belongsTo-namedQuery , instantiation-hasMany and  belongsTo-hasMany.

```
Scenario 1:

class Question
{
  String quesText
  static constraints={}
  static namedQueries={
    getAllQuestionOptions{question->
      return QuestionOption.findAllWhere(question:question)
    }
  }
}

class QuestionOption
{
  String optionText
  Question question
  static constraints={}
}
```

.

```
Scenario 2:
class Question
{
  String quesText
  static constraints={}
  static namedQueries={
    getAllQuestionOptions{question->
      return QuestionOption.findAllWhere(question:question)
    }
  }
}

class QuestionOption
{
  String optionText
  static constraints={}
  static belongsTo=[question:Question]
}
```

.

```
Scenario 3:
class Question
{
  String quesText
  static constraints={}
  static hasMany=[questionOption:QuestionOption] 
}

class QuestionOption
{
  String optionText
  Question question
  static constraints={}
}
```

.

```
Scenario 4:
class Question
{
  String quesText
  static constraints={}
  static hasMany=[questionOption:QuestionOption] 
}

class QuestionOption
{
  String optionText
  static constraints={}
  static belongsTo=[question:Question]
}
```

I used all these scenarios with mysql and all resulted with same schema

```
mysql> desc question;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| version     | bigint(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ques_text   | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc question_option;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| version     | bigint(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| option_text | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| question_id | bigint(20)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

What is difference between using these scenarios in the terms of cascading , unidirectional-bidirectional and aggregation-composition?
Bidirectional means when both entity knows about each other.Unidirectional means first entity know about second but reverse is not true.
To understand cascading I referred this: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-cascade-example-save-update-delete-and-delete-orphan/ .
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`belongsTo` and `hasMany` associations in Grails effect the [cascading](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/GORM.html#cascades) behavior when it relates to updating/deleting instances. It has no effect on the named queries or querying in general.

Comment: Thanks.From above info:Scenario 2 and 4 having similarity of cascade strategy is set to ALL for the owning side of the relationship and NONE from other side and with diff that scenario 4 must be used for Bidirectional one-to-many and scenario 2 for Unidirectional one-to-one.Scenario 3 is Bidirectional one-to-many with cascade strategy is set to SAVE-UPDATE.Bidirectional means when both entity knows about each other.Unidirectional means first entity know about second but not reverse.What is the difference between Scenario 1 and 2 (composition)?What is diff b/w cascade strategy ALL & SAVEUPDATE?